# Read specific lines from text file as numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a txt file in he format:

```
[text]
[text]
[text]
1 0 
4 5
3 0 0
[text]
.
.
.
```

I need to read lines 4 to 6 as a numpy array. So far I've got:

```
 lines=[]
 with open('filename', "r") as f:
     for i, line in enumerate(f):
         if i>=3 and i<=5:
             lines.append(line)
 lines = np.array(lines)
```

This reads each of the required lines as an element, but I need to have numbers in separate columns as separate elements. Is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Split lines on space?

Comment: But then I can't set it as a numpy array. Comes up with error: "setting an array element with a sequence"

Comment: Your last number line has 3 numbers, the others 2?  Do you really want that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform string to ints:

```
lines=[]
with open('filename', "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(x.split('\n')):
        if i>=3 and i<=5:
            lines.append([int(y) for y in line.split()])

lines = np.array(lines)
print type(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.islice()` to select the lines and feed that result to Numpy's `genfromtxt()` function:

```
from itertools import islice
import numpy as np

with open('test.txt') as lines:
    array = np.genfromtxt(islice(lines, 3, 6))

print array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `skiprows` and `max_rows` in numpy.

```
array = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=3,max_rows=3)
```

`max_rows`: number of rows you want to read afters skipping `skiprows` initial rows.