# read numpy array from txt file by chunks

Tags: numpy, txt

I have a 2D array saved in txt file(10 millions rows). Because it's too large, I need to load it by chunk. Let's say read every 1000 lines each time (as a batch size of training data in Neural Network). Now I followed this :

[Read specific lines from text file as numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969828/read-specific-lines-from-text-file-as-numpy-array)

It works well. But it is way too slow. Is there any other way to do this please?

```
from itertools import islice
import numpy as np
data=np.ones((10000000,100))  
# This is sample data

#I saved data using 
outfile= ('data.txt','wb') 
np.savetxt(outfile, data) 
#Now load data
file = open('data.txt','rb')
array = np.genfromtxt(islice(file, 1000000,1000005))
```

Or is there any other way to save and load data by chunks faster?